# Inconsistent output in Nashorn after accessing undefined value

Tags: java, nashorn

I'm trying to create a console interface to a Java program using Nashorn. So I want some input to be evaluated against some default imports. The problem is when it accesses an undefined value. Ideally, `engine.eval` should throw a `ReferenceError`, or return `null`, but I'm getting inconsistent values later on:

```
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("nashorn");
        System.out.println(engine.eval("with(JavaImporter(java.util)) { x }"));
        System.out.println(engine.eval("with(JavaImporter(java.util)) { x = 1 }"));
        System.out.println(engine.eval("with(JavaImporter(java.util)) { x }"));
    }
}
```

The result on [ideone](http://ideone.com/fmq6nC) and Windows Oracle JDK 1.8.0_101 is:

```
null
1
null
```

The last output is `null`, but adding `x == null` gives false.

I get this output if I add any spaces to the first string:

```
null
1
1
```

It seems that the last value is `null` if the first and last `engine.eval` parameters are exactly the same, including whitespace.

The value of `x` can go back between `null` and `1` so it looks like some kind of caching in the engine:

```
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("nashorn");
        System.out.println(engine.eval("with(JavaImporter(java.util)) { x }"));
        System.out.println(engine.eval("with(JavaImporter(java.util)) { x = 1 }"));
        System.out.println(engine.eval("with(JavaImporter(java.util)) { x }"));
        System.out.println(engine.eval("with(JavaImporter(java.util)) { x  }"));
        System.out.println(engine.eval("with(JavaImporter(java.util)) { x + x }"));
        System.out.println(engine.eval("with(JavaImporter(java.util)) { x }"));
    }
}
```

Gives:

```
null
1
null
1
2.0
null
```

Is there someway to get this to consistently give the `null, 1, 1` results?

Comment: `x`'s value is *undefined*, not *null*. It is merely converted to *null* by `engine.eval` in order to return it to java. Have you tried `x === undefined` (note `===` and not `==`, `==` is just... bad, in javascript. It has very inconsistent behavior)?.

Comment: I used `==` to include the possibility of it being `undefined` or `null` but it doesn't matter what code I use, any change and it is treated as `1` again. Replacing `x` with `x + x` gives 2, even adding a space around the `x` gives 1. It's like the result of the string is being cached by the engine and it's ignoring any changes to the value.

Comment: I think this may be a bug in nashorn when falling back to non-strict mode ( though I haven't found any references). It is important to note that the `with(...){ ... }` syntax is deprecated and not supported with `"use strict";`. Completely removing the `with` statement makes nashorn complain that the variable was not declared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a class cache within the engine, which can be disabled by creating it with:

```
NashornScriptEngineFactory factory = new NashornScriptEngineFactory();
ScriptEngine engine = factory.getScriptEngine(new String[] { "--class-cache-size = 0" });
```

By forcing each expression to be recompiled, it seems to solve the issue. It looks like the same expression is compiled differently depending on which variables are in scope.

Answer (score 0):

Force the engine to acknowledge the declaration of the variable.

Just use `var x` in the first script.

`System.out.println(engine.eval("with(JavaImporter(java.util)) { var x }"));
   System.out.println(engine.eval("with(JavaImporter(java.util)) { x = 1 }"));
   System.out.println(engine.eval("with(JavaImporter(java.util)) { x }"));`